# Angular passing service array from component to html in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 5, I have created an service for data

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { prmDataField } from '../_models/index'

 @Injectable()
 export class prmService {

    prmDataFields = [
new prmDataField('Training & Recruitment', 'expenses', 'billNo', 'totalAmt')];
 }
```

component.ts:

```
import { prmService } from '../data.service';
constructor(private prmDataLabel: prmService) {}
```

compontent.html

[image]

There are textbox under this head which are in service.ts, I want to load prmDataFields data to this textbox onload of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service:

```
getFields() {

  prmDataFields: any[] = [
    new prmDataField('Training & Recruitment', 'expenses', 'billNo', 'totalAmt')
  ];

  return prmDataFields;
}
```

In your component:

```
this.fields = this.prmDataLabel.getFields()
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields"> ... </div>
```

Take a look at this [**demo**](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz) from the Angular docs to get an idea of how dynamic forms should work. It would also be a good idea to read through the [**example**](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) for this demo as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your component you should define a variable to hold the `prmDataFields`:

`prmDataFields = this.prmService.prmDataFields` then

You loop through the array with `ngFor` to display wherever your text box is:

```
<div *ngFor="let dataField of prmDataFields">
    {{ dataField }}
</div>
```